# wacky blackberry Z10 rendering - simple table rendering

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-10

I was having trouble rendering an html page properly in Blackberry Z10. I kept simplifying  page until I realized that unit was having trouble rendering simplest of table properly. Here is code and screen shot below. It appears that when Blackberry hits third line of td in table, it decides to explode the font.

```
<html5>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>Line 1</p>
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345         
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>        
            <p>Line 2</p>       
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            12345678901234 12345678901234 12345
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
            <p>Line 3</p>       
            12345678901234 12345678901234 123456
            12345678901234 12345678901234 123456
            12345678901234 12345678901234 123456
            12345678901234 12345678901234 123456
            12345678901234 12345678901234 123456
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

[image]

... similar behavior on unordered list
When text extends to third line, font expands for all lines in unordered list!

I have os 10.1. Can someone confirm if this was problem on os10? or Q10?